# Is it a good idea to implement a software application in C# and then convert it to Python?

Tags: programming-languages

My project is about an automatic HTML documentation generator. The final product can't be in C# because of some organizational and legal constraints.

To my experience, Python is harder to debug than C#, primarily because it is only weakly typed. Hence I thought I could implement my project in C# and then convert it to Python.

Is this a sound approach, which could help me to create the software faster and avoid bugs? What can go wrong with this way of doing things?

Comment: If you do go that route: [`transpile C# to Python`](https://www.google.com/search?q=transpile+C%23+to+Python) might help.

Comment: What do you hope to gain with the conversion?

Comment: Why the down votes? I think it is a good question. It might not be a great idea, but a good question to ask whether it is a good idea.

Comment: @Helena because the question doesn't explain why you can't just use the C# application once you've written it

Comment: @Helena: "Goodness" is subjective. Unless the OP provides a precise, unambiguous, objectively measurable definition of what, *exactly*, makes an idea "good", the question is asking for opinions, which is off-topic.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, edited.

Comment: *"Python is hard to debug. Coz, it doesn't have types"* - Python certainly does have types - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datatypes.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328920/is-python-strongly-typed furthermore, the existence of types in a language shouldn't particularly make much difference to how easy or hard it may be to debug a program.  Debugging is more down to the tools that you use as well as ensuring your code is well-written, well-structured, written defensively, with appropriate automated test coverage, as well as sufficient logging and observability.

Comment: To add to the above comment, Python is even optionally statically typed. It supports type annotations, the `typing` module for related utilities, and the `mypy` type checker. Mypy relates to Python in a similar way that TypeScript relates to JavaScript. Of course Python's typing is fairly limited and weak (especially if the Any type is allowed), but it has helped me catch lots of bugs.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I think the question, as it is written now, is pretty clear about its goals. It may be too opinionated for some community members' taste, but it is definitely not unclear.

Comment: Implementing things in a language X and then converting it to language Y is not uncommon, especially when X is providing betters means of abstractions, better tooling etc. For example, where X is C or C++, and Y is assembly with SSE instructions, for optimization purposes.  However, I don't think this applies to a combination where X is C# and Y is Python, or vice versa. Both are languages with a rich ecosystem for their common implementations, and maintaining a program in these languages in parallel, with a manual conversion, will probably produce more problems than it will solve.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious risk here that you introduce bugs while "converting" it to Python - scare quotes as it's going to be more of a complete rewrite than a real conversion, particularly if you depend on any nontrivial C# libraries.

Of course, you can reduce that risk by having a thorough integration/system test suite... but if you have a thorough test suite, you may as well just write it in Python in the first place, so I don't see what this scheme will gain you.

It sounds to me like you probably just need to practice your debugging skills in Python; the lack of types doesn't make it harder to debug as and of itself, but it is a different language in many ways.

Comment: An interesting case is when the application is tested using system tests: if it's a web service, the tests can perform HTTP requests and check the responses; if it's a console app, the tests can call the app using different inputs, and check the outputs. Then, the application can be ported to virtually any programming language, without modifying the tests. Or the tests can be rewritten in a different language, while the application would remain the same.

Comment: Absolutely, it's integration/system tests which provide the value here. No point writing unit tests for the C# code.